# como desvincular una aplicacion de Flutter en Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Tengo un pequeño problema con mi app, en pricipio es una app sencilla lo unico que tiene es un boton, que cuando le das click, te devuelve una subcoleccion de Firestore

El problema comienza cuando a la app la saque del proyecto que estaba en firebase que se llamba crud (como se muestra en la foto) y la pase a otro proyecto que se llama flamma y borre el proyecto crud, el tema es que sigue "contectado" a ese proyecto de firebase y no obtiene los nuevos campos del nuevo proyecto, ya probe haciendo un Wipe al emulador, agrege el nuevo google-sevice.json que te da google al agregar a la app y sigo sin poder conectarme al nuevo proyecto

[image: codigo de error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para desvincular el proyecto de flutter de Firebase por mas que este quede como conectado lo que hice fue hacer un `Flutter clean` luego un `flutter pub get`